# How can I compile a program with Intel's Memory Protection Extensions (MPX) on a Mac?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, cpu, intel

I am trying to test out Intel's Memory Protection Extensions (MPX) on my Macbook Pro by mirroring [this tutorial for Linux](https://01.org/blogs/2016/intel-mpx-linux). My processor is an Intel Core i5-6267U and it does have the ability to use MPX as verified by running `sysctl machdep.cpu | grep MPX`. However, when I try to compile the following test program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define noinline __attribute__((noinline))

char dog[] = "dog";
char password[] = "secr3t";

noinline
char dog_letter(int nr)
{
        return dog[nr];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int max = sizeof(dog);
        int i;

        if (argc >= 2)
                max = atoi(argv[1]);

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
                printf("dog[%d]: '%c'\n", i, dog_letter(i));

        return 0;
}
```

with the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -o mpx_test -fcheck-pointer-bounds -mmpx mpx_test.c
```

I get the following string of errors:

```
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:26:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
        bnd jle L2
                ^
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:37:11: error: unexpected token in argument list
        bnd call        _atoi
                        ^
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:41:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
        bnd jmp L3
                ^
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:45:11: error: unexpected token in argument list
        bnd call        _dog_letter
                        ^
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:57:9: error: unexpected token in argument list
        bnd jl  L4
                ^
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:61:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bnd'
        bnd ret
        ^~~
/var/folders/v0/g_jfwt1j0kj1cp6vjn818jjh0000gn/T//cc5F0fho.s:88:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bnd'
        bnd ret
        ^~~
```

If I compile with the -S flag, I can see that the assembly GCC generates does have the MPX-specific instructions (`bnd...`). What else do I need to do to compile the program with MPX protections?

Comment: Didn't GCC remove MPX support?

Comment: It looks like Apple's assembler hasn't been updated to understand MPX yet. This probably means the kernel and C library don't support MPX either. You're going to have to wait for a new version of OSX that supports this feature.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons they did in version 9.3 or something, this is why I am using version 8. :)

Comment: @zwol this would not effect my use of MPX in a virtual machine though, would it?

Comment: What virtual machine?  I've read that MPX has also been removed from the Linux kernel.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons version 3.19 where it hasn't been removed.

Comment: If you want to run your code in a VM, compile it in the VM.  What you're doing is compiling *and assembling* into MachO64 object files MacOS so you'd have a hard time running it on Linux even if you left out `-fcheck-pointer-bounds -mmpx`

Comment: I don't know if MPX needs support from the hypervisor and/or outer operating system in order to be used inside a VM. You may as well try it.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean compile it on the Mac and then run it in the VM. I meant do everything in the VM. I will test things out - thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Why are you bothering to test out [a technology that's deprecated](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/introduction-to-intel-memory-protection-extensions.html)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I want to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround that allows me to use MPX on my Mac - though it is really only viable for small programs. The steps I took to get MPX working for **kernel space** are as follows:

1. Enable MPX. Refer to the Intel manual for how to do this. In short, one needs to write some bits to a MSR.
2. Startup a Linux VM or hop on any other system that has an assembler that supports MPX.
3. On this second system, write out the MPX assembly instructions (that you want for the program back on the Mac) and assemble the program.
4. Disassemble the program via `objdump -d` and copy the opcodes for the relevant MPX instructions and operands into inline assembly on the Mac.
5. Compile and run on the Mac :)

This should also work for MPX in user space with a slight change in how MPX is enabled (`XSAVE` instructions for user space and a MSR for kernel space).

As an example of what the inline assembly on the Mac could look like after copying the opcodes, consider the following.

```
__asm__ volatile (
        ".byte 0xf3, 0x0f, 0x1b, 0x40, 0x10     \t\n" // bndmk 16(%rax), %bnd0
        ".byte 0xf2, 0x0f, 0x1a, 0x40, 0x16     \t\n" // bndcu 22(%rax), %bnd0
        :
        : "a" (some_input)
    );
```

Comment: That inline-asm statement doesn't tell the compiler that `-16(%rbp)` is an input.  You're relying purely on dead-reckoning here for it to actually have the right pointer in the same place on the stack between your Linux and Mac builds.  Instead you should be asking for a pointer input in a specific register like `asm volatile (".byte ..." : : "a"(some_local));`  You only read that GP register, and GCC doesn't know about BND regs so you don't need to declare clobbers on them.  However you do I think also need to declare a dummy memory input so the pointed-to memory `16(%rax)` is also an input.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for all the helpful  comments. I changed my inline assembly to reflect your comment.  Let me know if I didn't understand you fully.

Comment: That is what I was suggesting, yes.  I think that's correct without a `"memory"` clobber because it's not actually accessing memory at `16(%rax)`; my earlier comment was wrong about that.  I had to remind myself how MPX works: [`bndmk`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bndmk) picks apart the addressing mode and uses `%rax` (in this case) as the lower bound, `16 + %rax` as the upper bound.  In my earlier comment I had guessed wrong that it was loading lower + upper bounds from memory at `16(%rax)`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it uses `%rax` as the lower bound and `16+%rax` as the upper bound. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So this code fragment just raises a `#BR` bound exception regardless of what value is in RAX on input, because it uses `bndcu` right after `bndmk` with an address outside the bounds.  I don't think this isn't a much of a step towards actually *using* MPX for practical purposes in code compiled for a Mac; for that I think you'd need to pass around bound registers and fence the compiler's access to memory so bound setup and checking happened before access.  Or maybe just faulting somewhere is ok, even if it's after loading or storing something.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, this will raise a `#BR` no matter what. For proof of concept that I could get some MPX instructions to execute I did the above and made sure I got a `#BR`, then I just went in and changed the 22 to something within bounds to check that being within bounds doesn't raise a `#BR`.

Comment: I'm just trying to caution you that I don't think it will be easy to get any practical use out of MPX with only inline asm; this technique is probably *only* viable for this toy experiment, although maybe with a `(reg, reg)` addressing mode you could ask for input in two registers...  If you already know about the limitations, that's fine if you just want to raise #BR to see what happens under MacOS, before going to the trouble of finding / creating a GCC + assembler that actually support MPX code-gen.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree, it is a hack just to play around with things a tiny bit. :)